# Flutter: How can I put an image behind another image

Tags: android, flutter

I have a photo frame image, I want to pick image from gallery and put that behind my frame image.

Is there any library or reference I can get?
I will need gesture such ass zoom in and zoom out as well on the background image.

I have very basic code running for me. I am able to show frame image in a container

```
body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 60),
        child: GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
            ),
            itemCount: getAssetCount(index),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Card(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Image(image: AssetImage(getResource(index, category))),
                    onTap: () => navigate(index),
                  )
              );
            }
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Can you please add a refrence design that you are looking and if any code that you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For this use Stack class

Create a widget Stack
in children  add two child 1st will be your back image and second  will be your front image

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html